# Static ArrayList in Application class

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
public class SharedVariables extends Application 
{
    public static ArrayList<clsNewsItem>  ArrayOfNewsItems;
}
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    ArrayOfNewsItems      = new ArrayList<clsNewsItem>();    
}
```

**hi i am declared Static Arraylist in application class. i am using this ArrayOfNewsItems in Some of the Activity classes And i will change ArrayOfNewsItems objects dynamically by clear() and Add() methods.**
My Question is, is it Good Practice to Change Static ArrayList of clsNewsItem objecs number of times..?
Can any one tell me please

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just about changing `ArrayList` then it doesn't seem to be bad practice. If you're using this container to pass some parameters from on activity to another then it may be a bad solution, but may be the only way to do what you want to do. It depends on the design of your application.